# ideals in the ring $\frac{F[x]}{(p(x))}$

Tags: polynomial-rings

> Exhibit all the ideals in the ring $\frac{F[x]}{(p(x))}$, where $F$ is a field and $p(x)$ is a polynomial in $F[x]$ (describe them in terms of the factorization of $p(x)$).

Let $p={p_1}^{k_1} {p_2}^{k_2} ... {p_n}^{k_n}$ where $p_i\in F[x]$ is irreducible.

The elements of $\frac{F[x]}{(p(x))}$ are of the form $(p(x))+q$ where $q={q_1}^{l_1} {q_2}^{l_2} ... {q_m}^{l_m}$ and if $p_i$ and $q_j$ are associates then $k_i>l_j$.

I tried Chinese remainder theorem but the ideals generated by irreducibles are not comaximal.

Please give a hint. Please do not give solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Use that 
$$(p(x),h(x)) = (\gcd(p(x),h(x))$$

Comment: @reuns But $(p(x))=({p_1}^{k_1}(x) {p_2}^{k_2}(x) ... {p_n}^{k_n}(x))$ and not $(p(x))=({p_1}^{k_1}(x), {p_2}^{k_2}(x), ... {p_n}^{k_n}(x))$. Where to use the equation you wrote?

Comment: $h\in F[x]$ is one of the generators of the ideal

Comment: @reuns Probably you are using that for an ideal $I$ of $\frac{F[x]}{(p(x))}$, $\exists h(x) \in F[x]$ s.t. $I=((p(x))+h(x))=(p(x), h(x))$ i.e. $\frac{F[x]}{(p(x))}$ is PID. But is $\frac{F[x]}{(p(x))}$ a PID?

Comment: $F[x]$ is a PID, thus so is $F[x]/(p(x))$

Comment: please refer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/567627/628415

Comment: A principal ideal ring...